# Selenium Opens Browser But Doesn't Get URL in neither Chrome nor Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

When I call `get()` webdriver will open the browser but not the click I'm requesting. In Firefox there is nothing where the URL should be and in Chrome instead of the URL there is the test __"data:,". Less than a month ago I had no issues using Selenium with Chrome using the same code I have now.

I am using:

- Selenium 3.141.0
- Chrome 71.0.3578.98
- Firefox 64.0
- chromedriver 2.45.615355
- geckodriver 0.23.0
- OSX 10.13.4
- Python 3.6.3

Here is the code I'm using to open Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login():
    driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Here is an output from the geckodriver logs:

1546726141780    mozrunner::runner    INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/s3/kjm0wk5516g_5scyf45d7mqw0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.YJ7piTvARrF3"

1546726142671    addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org    WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/

1546726142671    addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org    WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
Can't find symbol 'GetGraphicsResetStatus'.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you're describing happens in Chrome when you just specify call `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` without calling the `driver.get(url)` function. From the code you mentioned, it doesn't seem that you're actually calling the `login()` method, which seems to confirm the behavior you're describing. When calling the `login()` function as shown below, Chrome directs to that url.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login():
    driver.get("https://google.com")

login()
```